# A computation by the Shapiro Lemma

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, cohomology

Hi:

When I read the book "An introduction to Homological algebra" by Weibel, the page 206, line 9 says that

"Shapiro's Lemma tell us that

$H_q(S_n(X)\otimes_{Z}A)$ is zero if $q\neq 0$ and is isomorphic to $S_n(X/G)\otimes_ZA$ if $q=0$" ,

here $Z$ is the ring of integers, $G$ is a group, $X$ is a path-connected topological space and $S_n(X)$ is the sequence of singular complex of $X$, and $A$ is an abelian group.

But I think is strange, and I can not prove this, also modify it.

I really want to know the correct statement and a proof for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that "$H_q(S_n(X)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A)$" should read "$H_q(G;S_n(X)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A)$".

Then 
$$H_0(G;S_n(X)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A)=(S_n(X)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A)_G = S_n(X/G)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A$$
by 6.10.2, and Shapiro's lemma gives $H_q(G; S_n(X)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A)= 0$ for $q>0$ since $$S_n(X)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A=\bigoplus\operatorname{Ind}^G_1 A$$ is induced from a module over the trivial group (sum is over the singular $n$-simplices of $X$).

Compare Brown's "Cohomology of groups", sections III.6 and VII.7.

Comment: Thank you very much! Since A is not alwayls torsion-free. Is this statement "$S_n(X)\otimes_Z A$ is a free $ZG$-module" replaced by "$S_n(X) \otimes_Z A=\oplus_I Ind^G_1 A$" for some set $I$? But I am confused by the assumption : $X$ is path-connected. Since it is never used here. Can we say more about this if $X$ is a path-connected topological space?

Comment: You're right, I've edited it now. That's a good point about the path-connected assumption - I couldn't find where it is used and have yet to figure out if its needed for the Cartan-Leray spectral sequence.